# split list two part in python using dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, split

i want to split list like this

```
[{'Age': '23', 'Name': 'John'}, {'Age': '43', 'Name': 'Apple'}, {'Age': '13', 'Name': 'Alice'}]
```

this is my code

```
temp_list=["John","Apple","Alice","23","43","13"]
temp_dict={'Name':'','Age':''}
final_list=[]
for temp in temp_list:
    temp_dict['Name']=temp
    temp_dict['Age']=temp
    final_list.append(temp_dict)
    temp_dict={'Name':'','Age':''}
print final_list
```

how can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following dict comprehension:

```
 final_list = dict(zip(temp_list[:3], temp_list[3:]))
```

Example:

```
>>> temp_list=["John","Apple","Alice","23","43","13"]
>>> final_list = dict(zip(temp_list[:3], temp_list[3:]))
>>> final_list
{'John': '23', 'Apple': '43', 'Alice': '13'}
```

In general, if `n = len(temp_list)` you can use:

```
final_list = dict(zip(temp_list[:n // 2], temp_list[n // 2:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

generate a structure you've specified in your question:

```
>>> [dict(zip(("Age", "Name"), x)) for x in zip(temp_list[3:], temp_list[:3])]
[{'Age': '23', 'Name': 'John'}, {'Age': '43', 'Name': 'Apple'}, {'Age': '13', 'Name': 'Alice'}]
```